# How to manage MySQL credentials of production server?

Tags: deployment, credentials

I have a simple Django application that needs to use a MySQL database. There is a file `settings.py` which contains a plain Python dictionary where I have to enter the MySQL credentials, it looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'django',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
     }
 }
```

On the server (Debian) I use a checkout of the latest git version of my application. In that git repo, I have a branch `production` which contains the database credentials that I have chosen for this server.

Now I would like to automate the deployment completely. Currently, I use Ansible to do a

```
git checkout production
git pull origin master
service apache2 restart
```

which works. The problem is that this database credential patch is on the server only. I would much rather have this patch centrally as well.

- I thought I could let Ansible do the deployment of the vanilla version and then use Ansible to exchange the `PASSWORD` line. The downside is that the next run of Ansible would detect that the checkout has been changed and redo everything, making it inefficient.
- Then I thought about a Debian package for the whole thing. This would require to either bake the credentials into the package, which I cannot do since the package is going to be public (to use a Launchpad PPA).

Either way, I probably need to have the credentials in some location where the vanilla deployment would find that, like `/etc/myapp/db.ini`.

What is a reasonable way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Secrets management is an extremely difficult problem. You don't ever want cleartext passwords in code.

There are a few tool out there for handling secrets, including Ansible Vault, Hashicorp Vault, and Keywhiz. I personally store secrets in S3 using KMS for encryption.

It's a difficult problem with several tools popping up to try to solve it. I would not presume to know the best solution for you, but I would advise looking at the various secrets management tools and select one that fits your needs.

Comment: This is a good comment it just isn't a comment.  Superuser is not a discussion forum, this would be a great response in a discussion forum, this just doesn't answer the author's question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. A bit new to contributing here, and I don't have enough rep yet to comment

Comment: So earn the reputation in order comment on other people's questions, what you don't do, is post comments as answers because you can't submit comments.  My first comment has a typo, it was suppose to say "great comment, it just isn't an answer", not whatever I said.